# GMail and IMAP access

Tags: google-workspace

I would like to disable POP and IMAP for Gmail, but enable it if IMAP connection is from an approved list of IP Addresses. Is this possible? I have looked at the GSuite Admin Page: https://support.google.com/a/answer/105694, but that only allows configuration at a Gmail user basis. What I need is "all users in the domain" have access from IMAP, but the user needs to be on the corporate intranet (with approved IP addresses). Is there a way to enforce this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such option at this moment. I was just looking into the same thing. I need to limit G Suite access to employees outside a specific IP range. Employees should be able to login from within the building, but not from outside. Same applies to IMAP/POP3 access.

G Suite support suggested to turn off IMAP/POP3 and use SSO third party application or make our own SSO endpoint and control access this way, but no solution if you want to block access to IMAP or POP3 ports.

It looks like G Suite does not have any firewall options for it's users at all.